# Data Insertion fails, but updating works on mysql - php using $stmt

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a serious problem!

I want to make an Edit Data form for my website, and I have a problem.
The thing I want to do, is that when a user clicks on the save button after editing his/her data, I want to update the database for those data, and that works, but I get an error. but it works.

The problem is, that when I want to insert new stuff (e.g a new user gives data to server) it doesn't work.

Please look at my codes and help me.

The PHP:

```
    $sql = "CALL AddOrModifyCompany(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);"; 
           if ($stmt = $con->prepare($sql)) 
           {
               $stmt->bind_param('isssssssss', $_ID,$Company_Name,$company_email,$company_phone,$country,$Town_Name,$Street,$contact_name,$contact_phone,$tax_number);
               $stmt->execute();
               $stmt->store_result(); 
           }
           else 
           {
               printf("Query failed: %s\n", $con->error);
           }
```

The MySql procedure:

```
    CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' PROCEDURE AddOrModifyCompany(IN `in_account_ID`INT(11), IN `in_company_name` VARCHAR(255), IN `in_Email` VARCHAR(255), IN `in_Phone` VARCHAR(255), IN `in_Country` VARCHAR(255), IN `in_Town` VARCHAR(255), IN `in_Street` VARCHAR(255), IN `in_ContactName` VARCHAR(255), IN `in_ContactPhone` VARCHAR(255), IN `in_TaxNumber` VARCHAR(255))
    BEGIN

    DECLARE TownId INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CountryId INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CompanyId INT DEFAULT 0;

    if (Select EXISTS(Select 1 from town Where town_Name = in_Town) = 1) THEN (Select id Into TownId from town Where town_Name = in_Town LIMIT 1);
    Else 

        if (SELECT EXISTS(Select 1 from countries Where Name = in_Country) = 1) THEN (Select id INTO CountryId from countries Where Name = in_Country LIMIT 1);
    Else 
  INSERT INTO countries (Name) VALUES (in_Country); 
  Set CountryId = LAST_INSERT_ID();
End IF;
      INSERT INTO town (town_Name, Country_Id) VALUES (in_Town,CountryId); 
       Set TownId = LAST_INSERT_ID();
      End IF;

      if  (SELECT EXISTS((Select 1 from accounts Where account_ID = in_account_ID AND company_ID = NULL))=1) THEN
      Insert Into companies(`company_name`, `company_phone`, `company_email`, `street_name`, `town_Id`, `contact_name`, `contact_phone`, `tax_number`) VALUES (in_company_name, in_Phone, in_Email, in_Street, TownId, in_ContactName, in_ContactPhone, in_TaxNumber);
      Update accounts SET company_ID =  LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE account_ID = in_account_ID;
    Else
      Select company_ID into CompanyId from accounts WHERE account_ID = in_account_ID;
      Update companies SET company_name = in_company_name, company_phone = in_Phone, company_email = in_Email, street_name = in_Street, town_Id=TownId, contact_name = in_ContactName, contact_phone = in_ContactPhone, tax_number = in_TaxNumber WHERE company_ID = CompanyId;
      End IF;

    END
```